# Axios how to get data from squared array

Tags: arrays, json, axios, nuxt.js

Hello im trying to get data from an API with axios and NUXT... i can get most of the data but not the one inside "**measurements**" like **"label"**...if someone can explain me how to go inside this squared array to get the label data ? it will be great...Thank you

[image]

Here is the axios script :

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
 export default {
   layout: 'women',
 data() {
  return {
    results: []
  }
},
 async mounted() {
  await axios.get("#######")
.then(response => {this.results = response.data.content})
 },
}
</script>


<b-col   v-for="result in results" :key="result"  class="wmgrd">
<p>{{result.measurements.label}}</p> 
</b-col>
```

Comment: `result.measurements` is an array of objects, not a nested object.

Comment: Thank you i will see what shoudl i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Smutje said is true. You're almost there. You have to loop over the measurements in case to access them.

You could do this in your response by making a new variable like `measurements: []`. After you set `this.results` you could loop over them like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.results.measurements.length; i++) {
    this.measurements.push(this.results.measurements[i]);
}
```

Then you can access measurements in your template and use it in the v-for.

The other way you could do it is by adding another tag in your template and put a v-for on this tag too. `v-for="measurement in result.measurements"`. After that, you should be able to access `measurement.label`.

Comment: Thank you very much ... i finally could get the data with your solution ..thats great